# Calculate the distance between 1st row lat long with 2nd row lat long

Tags: sql, sql-server, distance, long-integer

I want to calculate the distance between current row latitude and longitude with next row latitude and longitude using SQL Server. Here is my table:

```
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| ID |    lat    |    lon     | distance |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 12.64464  | 77.56497   | 15.446   |
|  2 | 12.9897   | 77.8989    | 16.46    |
|  3 | 12.898    | 77.4478979 | 17.89    |
|  4 | 12.646879 | 77.689897  | 18.47    |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far to solve this problem.

Comment: I am Using distance formula

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) page. It might give you the solution that you are looking for.